# How can I shorten this 2D array code?

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following snippet which works fine.

```
P=im1.copy()
for i in range(P.shape[0]):
    for j in range(P.shape[1]):
        if (n_dens.data[i][j]==-5000 or T_k.data[i][j]==-5000):
            P.data[i][j]=-5000
        else :
            P.data[i][j]=n_dens.data[i][j]*T_k.data[i][j]
```

where `P` is a 2D array.

I was wondering how to trim this down to something along the following lines:

```
P.data=n_dens.data*T_k.data
P.data=[foo-2.5005*10**7 if n_dens.data==-5000 or T_k.data==-5000 else foo for foo in P.data]
```

For my trial above I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I correct the error? Or is there another method to trim it down?

Comment: I think you mean to have the line below the `else:` indented by one more level (because as your code currently stands, it would raise an `IndentationError`).

Comment: Whatever you choose, remember that **readable code is more important then one-liner**

Comment: Advice for improvement of working code isn't generally StackOverflow's focus, as we try to be a repository for answers to specific, narrow problems that avoids questions that can be subjective matters of opinion -- our sister site [codereview.se] is often more appropriate, though the rules there are quite different. See [A Guide to Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for guidance on which questions are appropriate where, and how to tailor them to be inside the rules for each site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
P.data[(n_dens.data == -5000) | (T_k.data == -5000)] = -5000
cond = ~(n_dens.data == -5000) & ~(T_k.data == -5000) # 2D array of booleans
P.data[cond] = n_dens.data[cond] * T_k.data[cond]
```

A complete example:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

class IMAGE:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.shape = self.data.shape

np.random.seed(0)
P, n_dens, T_k = IMAGE(np.zeros((5,5))), IMAGE(np.reshape(np.random.choice([-5000,1,2],25), (5,5))), IMAGE(3*np.ones((5,5)))
P1 = deepcopy(P)

# with loop
for i in range(P.shape[0]):
    for j in range(P.shape[1]):
        if (n_dens.data[i][j]==-5000 or T_k.data[i][j]==-5000):
            P.data[i][j]=-5000
        else :
            P.data[i][j]=n_dens.data[i][j]*T_k.data[i][j]

# vectorized
P1.data[(n_dens.data == -5000) | (T_k.data == -5000)] = -5000
cond = ~(n_dens.data == -5000) & ~(T_k.data == -5000) # 2D array of booleans
P1.data[cond] = n_dens.data[cond] * T_k.data[cond]

cond
# array([[False,  True, False,  True,  True],
#   [ True, False,  True, False, False],
#   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#   [False,  True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

# with same output for both
P.data == P1.data
# array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `n_dens.data==-5000` produces an array of true/false values, not a single value. So, the `if` can't handle it. You are close to the idea though. You can use *logical indexing* in numpy.

Also logical operators cannot be overloaded in python. So, numpy does not handle them as you would wish. So, you have to do something like

```
index = np.logical_or(n_dens.data ==-5000, T_k.data==-5000)
P.data[index] = -5000
```

Similarly, `P.data[np.logical_not(index)] = n_dens.data * T.data` for the second branch of if-else.